# Window's root view controller is not Split view controller

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode6, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to modify my existing app to use a split view controller.  I've followed the sample master/detail project structure by adding a split view controller into my storyboard, made it the initial view controller and everything seemed to be working fine, until I tried to run the app in an iOS 7 simulator.  All of a sudden when I hit my breakpoint in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` `self.window.rootViewController` is now the type of my master view controller, not the split view controller itself.

I thought maybe then I just need to get the split view controller off of the root view itself and tried `rootViewController.splitViewController` but that is `nil`.  I must have missed some set up step in enabling this split view controller, but I have no idea what it was.

Comment: Could you add a link to the guide you followed in setting up the Split View Controller in the Storyboard?

Comment: I didn't follow a guide, I just added the split view controller to the storyboard, set it as the initial view controller, and hooked up my master and detail views to the appropriate outlets.  If I even take the same storyboard generated by the base master/detail view project and put it into my project the same behavior happens (master view controller is the root view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this ended up being a pretty obscure issue.  It seemed to be caused by the way that the iOS 8 SDK and Xcode 6 handle storyboards and size classes.  I intend to file a bug report with apple but the repro steps to get this to present are simple:

1. Create a new master/detail application
2. Set deployment target to below 8.0 (7/7.1 works)
3. Change application type from "Universal" to "iPad"
4. You have to comment out this line from the generated app delegate, it will crash in an iOS 7 target:

   ```
   navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
   ```
5. Run on iPad simulator for iOS 7.1

The fix to this issue is to disable size classes on the storyboard.  I theorize that the way that Xcode 6 and the iOS 8 SDK are handling size classes for iPad versus universal app builds causes this to not work on iOS 7 targets, but turning off size classes fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `UISplitViewController` isn't supported in iPhone in iOS7, only in iPad.

If you run your code in iPad iOS7 you will see your `UISplitViewController`.

Only in iOS8 Apple added support for iPhone as well.

Comment: @DanF oh sorry, didn't know. I edited the answer with a code that worked for me. Please tell me if it works

Comment: Even if I try to get the split view controller property of the root view controller, that is still nil

Comment: Well, just tried it with a navigationController and without, in both cases I do get the self.window.rootViewController as splitViewcontroller. So I guess my answer has no real value as I didn't able to see your problem. What kind is you master viewController, or maybe post a screenshot with your storyBoard

Comment: Doesn't matter what the master is, it is something wrong with the project.  I created a new project with the master/detail template and took that project's storyboard and make it the default storyboard of my project and I replicate the same issue.  If I take my storyboard and put it into the master/detail template project it behaves normally.  It has nothing to do with the storyboard, just the project